# Applying jQuery UI CSS to MVC .input-validation-error

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, validation

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC app.  I am at the client side validation part.  I found that when the UI flashes an error, it uses the class .input-validation-error.

What do I have to do in order to successfully make this class the same as what the jQuery UI uses for Alert CSS.

If you go to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and look at the lower right you'll see an Alert box.  What is the correct way to use this styling for my input validation error class?

I am very new to MVC so am not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is put that line of code in partial view and pass the message or view model to that partial view.

```
<div id="error-effect" class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;"> 
    <div style="margin-top:12px;">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span> 
    <strong>Error:</strong> 
    "Your message goes here"
   </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have imported the JQuery classes correctly, it should display the way it does on themeroller page.

Comment: I'll udpate this post with credit as soon as I get a chance to try it.